# Extracting column name from table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

df:

```
ID  Date   A B C
1  201901  4 5 2
1  201902  3 4 2
```

I have another table:
df1:

```
 Columns
  B
  C
```

While keeping the ID, and Date column.. and I trying to use the columns given in the table as well.

Currently I am using,

```
  df1 = list(df1['Columns']
  df1 = ''.join(df1)
  df = df[['ID','Date',df1]]
  print(df)
```

This method isn't working for me.

While I can manually insert B and C.. i need a generalized code that can work with any given table.

Expected output:

```
   ID  Date   B C
   1  201901  5 2
   1  201902  4 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `df1`, you need extract values from `Columns` column of `df1`.

```py
df = df[['ID','Date']+df1['Columns'].values.tolist()]
```

If your `Columns` of `df1` contains column not in `df` column header, you may need to filter some out

```py
common = list(set(df1.columns.tolist()).intersection(df.columns.tolist()))

df = df[['ID','Date']+common]
```

Comment: for some reason, when i run this... i only get the ID and Date column.

Comment: @tjjudge What's the output of `df1['Columns'].tolist()`? How about adding parentheses like `df = df[(['ID','Date']+df1['Columns'].tolist())]`?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `reindex`

```
out = df.reindex(['ID','Date']+df1.Columns.tolist(),axis=1)
Out[33]: 
   ID    Date  B  C
0   1  201901  5  2
1   1  201902  4  2
```